# Ajax jQuery returning only one row of data from C# Web Method - Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to display multiple rows of data in a chart.js bar chart, I've got the chart displaying my live data from SQL & C# Web Method. However, when in the chart it only shows 1 row of data and thus 1 bar. How to I get all the rows to display in the bar chart?

The amount of rows can change so I don't want to restrict how many return, I know I need some sort of loop, but not sure where to start.

I'm using ASP.Net C#

**Ajax/jQuery Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("Start");

        var description = jQuery('Description').toArray();
        var applicantSourceCount = jQuery('ApplicantSourceCount').toArray();
        var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("ReportingDashboard.aspx/GetApplicantSourceData") %>';

        function chartData() {
            console.log("load Function");

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{Description:"' + description + '", ApplicantSourceCount:"' + applicantSourceCount + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //alert(data);
                    var aData = data.d;
                    var aLabels = data.d["0"].Description;
                    var aDataSet = data.d["0"].ApplicantSourceCount;

                    console.log(aLabels);
                    console.log("load chart data");
                    console.log(data.d["0"].ApplicantSourceCount);
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: aLabels.split(','),
                            datasets: [{
                                label: "Applicant Source",
                                data: aDataSet.split(','),
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                                    "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)"
                                ],
                                borderColor:[
                                    "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
                                    "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                                    "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
                                    "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
                                    "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                                    "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
                                    "rgb(201, 203, 207)"
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 3
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("chartDrawEnd");
                }
            }); 
        }
        chartData();            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly how your json response is formatted, but in general, what I believe you are looking for is the ability to enter multiple datasets. If you'll notice, the `datasets` field is an array consisting of Javascript objects that have a label, data, and some background color. One possible option would be to create a for loop that loops through your returned json, gets the information needed for the dataset, creates a corresponding javascript object, and then adds that javascript object to an array. Then, just pass the array into the `datasets` field.

Comment: I'd have to do the same thing with the labels in that case as well..I'm returning two columns of data with 11 rows; Description (Source) and a count of the total rows for each Source. I've tried `var aDataSet = data.d["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"].ApplicantSourceCount;` but it just returns the last value